# How are DNS records updated to all DNS servers on the internet?

Tags: dns

If someone hosts a hostname/website name on GoDaddy, OpenDNS, etc., how would they update the record of DNS servers across the world for that newly added hostname? Since there are lots of DNS servers on the internet, and every ISP provides different DNS servers for their clients.

Answer (score 38):

They don't.  (Simplifying just a little bit) DNS is a hierarchy.  DNS servers know either how to find a parent DNS server or how to find a list of the "root" servers.

If they find a parent DNS server they just ask it, and it asks its parent until it gets an authoritative answer.

In most cases however, nameservers know the root nameservers, which in turn point them to the appropriate servers for the domain.  (Or in some cases the appropriate server for the first part of the domain.  This process is repeated until the domain name is resolved).

Below is an example of a "trace" which shows how the system could authoritatively resolve an IP address for [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (ignoring signatures):

Cut down output from Linux command "dig +trace www.google.com"

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> +trace www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
.           514683  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           514683  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
;; Received 525 bytes from 10.0.3.254#53(10.0.3.254) in 13 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.


google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
;; Received 840 bytes from 192.33.14.30#53(b.gtld-servers.net) in 35 ms

www.google.com.     300 IN  A   172.217.25.36
;; Received 59 bytes from 216.239.36.10#53(ns3.google.com) in 178 ms
```

1. The first query looks up the root servers (*.root-servers.net)
2. Then the root servers advise where to find the rightmost part of the domain - ".com"
3. The third query returns the nameservers for google.com
4. Finally Google's nameservers advise the answer for [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

I note in the example above I've manually stripped the query result to its bare essentials.  In reality a nameserver won't generally make all of these queries, because it will remember parts of it.  That is, the first time someone looks up any .com domain name, the DNS server they are using will remember the nameservers (for 172800 seconds in this case), so it won't need to do another lookup.  Similarly for all the more specific parts of the lookup.

So if someone is registering example.com via GoDaddy (or any registrar), GoDaddy needs to (programmatically) get the nameservers for example.com entered into the ".com" nameserver.     Similarly, if they are in AU, they need to enter the information into the ".com.au" space if they want to register "example.com.au" - and this would require an agreement with the people controlling the nameservers for ".com.au" space - which is why not all registrars can register all domains, and why getting new top level domains is such a process - they need to pay big money to register the TLD with the root nameservers.

Comment: Note that the recursive search may take several steps, potentially one for each level. Each reply comes with a cache-time, the one for ".com" will probably be for 7 days, the other ones for 1 day. A DNS server should cache as much as possible

Comment: @csm - A DNS server should not cache as much as possible. It should cache as instructed by the TTLs in the zones as excessive caching is bad. Also, while latency is detectable, lookups are incredibly cheap CPU and band with wise.

Comment: @davidgo DNS requests have crashed the internet before. Part of the reason is that it is easy to generate bandwidth starving requests with recursive DNS. A simple DNS request is around 20 bytes and generates around 200 bytes of response. Coupled with recursive requests, say for example 4 hops - thats 800 bytes of traffic generated from 20 bytes of request. Because of this most ISP and DNS services won't simply cache as instructed by the zone's TTL. Instead they will have minimum TTL. Most providers will not accept a TTL of less than 10 minutes

Comment: @slebetman Which will impact use of CDN services like Akamai, which use DNS to redirect traffic as quickly as possible around failing and overloaded servers. They use TTLs like 5-10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to check my TTLs.