# Default Gateway acting as DNS

Tags: dns

Is it true that if the created DNS server was unable to resolve requests, the Default Gateway will act as a DNS server using the DNS IPs in its router?

I tried to setup a DNS server and remove all DNS ip in the forwarders. I also put the IP of the DNS server I created in the Primary dns field in network adapter. Since I removed all the DNS IP as forwarders, I expect the client to not able to resolve it. Yet it still pings www.google.com? I flushed the dns btw.

DNS server ip is - 10.0.2.4 while Default gateway of DNS server and client is the same - 10.0.2.1

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy for you to answer the question yourself – install a 'packet capture' tool (e.g. Wireshark or tcpdump) on your DNS server and let it monitor the DNS resolution process. It will show *exactly* which servers are being contacted.

> Is it true that if the created DNS server was unable to resolve requests, the Default Gateway will act as a DNS server using the DNS IPs in its router?

No. If you manually configured different DNS servers in Windows, then it will *only* use those servers – it will not automatically use the gateway. There is no rule that gateways should provide DNS.

(However, be careful that both IPv4 and IPv6 have *separate* "DNS server" settings pages. Even if you set IPv4 to manual, it could still be that IPv6 remains on "automatic" and keeps receiving the "DNS server" advertisement from your gateway. Always check `ipconfig /all` to make sure it is not showing unwanted DNS servers.)

> I tried to setup a DNS server and remove all DNS ip in the forwarders. I also put the IP of the DNS server I created in the Primary dns field in network adapter. Since I removed all the DNS IP as forwarders, I expect the client to not able to resolve it. Yet it still pings www.google.com?

If your DNS server software has `forwarder` settings, then it usually means the server is also capable of performing the full iterative query process *on its own* as well.

In other words – your server itself does exactly the same thing as the "forwarders" would do. (You have already seen the process [explained in another thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1533833/how-dns-records-are-updated-to-all-dns-servers-in-the-internet).)

But note that unlike the example shown in davidgo's post, DNS servers actually don't need to look up the list of "root servers" in step 1 – they already come with this list *built in*. This means forwarders are completely unnecessary for the process to work.